# Facebook4j Post Tracking Issue

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My application is a keyword tracker application that captures user sentiments that relate to our business. The application was working fine. But from last two weeks it doesn’t capture some relevant post. However, when I directly use Facebook Graph API it captured all posts. Is there any blockage like this? Since this application is in the production environment I’m in bit critical status. Please be kind enough to advise me for further processing.

Thanks in advance,
Asha Perera

```html
import facebook4j.Facebook;
import facebook4j.FacebookException;
import facebook4j.FacebookFactory;
import facebook4j.Post;
import facebook4j.ResponseList;
import facebook4j.conf.Configuration;
import facebook4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class Main {

 Facebook facebook = null;

 public void initiateStream() {

  ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
  confBuilder.setOAuthAppId("*******");
  confBuilder.setOAuthAppSecret("********");
  confBuilder.setPrettyDebugEnabled(true);
  confBuilder.setHttpProxyHost("******");
  confBuilder.setHttpProxyPort(8080);
  confBuilder.setHttpProxyUser("*******");
  confBuilder.setHttpProxyPassword("*******");
  confBuilder

    .setOAuthPermissions("read_stream, user_status, friends_status,email, publish_stream, id, name, first_name, last_name, generic");
  confBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
  confBuilder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);

  // Create configuration object
  Configuration configuration = confBuilder.build();

  FacebookFactory fbFactory = new FacebookFactory(configuration);
  Facebook facebook = fbFactory.getInstance();

  try {
   facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(facebook.getOAuthAppAccessToken());
   ResponseList<Post> results = facebook.searchPosts("kid_2");

   for (Post post : results) {
    System.out.println(post.getMessage());
   }

  } catch (FacebookException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Main main = new Main();
  main.initiateStream();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public Post Search has been deprecated with Graph API v2. Possible that you still use an v1.0 app, but this is only guaranteed to work until April 30th, 2015. Have a look at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

Comment: Hi Tobi, Thanks for your reply. Is there any alternative to this in V2??